# Fire notification toaster in any controller angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using this service for notifications: https://github.com/jirikavi/AngularJS-Toaster
Is working perfectly. Already configured for that anywhere in my application I create a pop () button, clicking the trigger notification toaster.
What I need now is any controller in my application, can call triggering the notification method.
For example, within the controller ProductController, I call pop () at any time and then the notification would be triggered.
Despite any view the pop () method function within the controller does not work at all.
Is there some detail I'm not watching?

My index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="app">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>My App</title>
  <meta name="description" content="app, web app, responsive, responsive layout, admin, admin panel, admin dashboard, flat, flat ui, ui kit, AngularJS, ui route, charts, widgets, components" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/simple-line-icons.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css" type="text/css" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/modules/toaster/toaster.css" type="text/css" />

</head>
<body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <div class="app" id="app" ng-class="{'app-header-fixed':app.settings.headerFixed, 'app-aside-fixed':app.settings.asideFixed, 'app-aside-folded':app.settings.asideFolded, 'app-aside-dock':app.settings.asideDock, 'container':app.settings.container}" ui-view></div>
  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="js/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Angular -->
  <script src="js/libs/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/angular/angular-cookies.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/angular/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/angular/angular-resource.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/angular/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/angular/ngStorage.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/angular/ocLazyLoad.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/angular/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
  <script src="js/angular/angular-translate.js"></script>
  <script src="js/angular/ui-jq.js"></script>
  <script src="js/angular/ui-load.js"></script>
  <script src="js/angular/ui-validate.js"></script>
  <!-- App -->
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/services.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controller-university.js"></script>
  <script src="js/filters.js"></script>
  <script src="js/directives.js"></script>

  <script src="js/modules/toaster/toaster.js"></script>
  <!-- Lazy loading -->
</body>
</html>
```

My view when the notification toaster is fire by click 'pop()' (it works perfectly):

```
<div class="bg-light lter b-b wrapper-md">
  <h1 class="m-n font-thin h3">Universities</h1>
</div>
<div class="wrapper-md">

  <!-- toaster directive -->
  <toaster-container toaster-options="{'position-class': 'toast-top-right', 'close-button':true}"></toaster-container>
  <!-- / toaster directive -->

      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <form name="formCreate" class="form-validation"  ng-submit="insert()">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <span class="h4">Create</span>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">

              <div class="form-group pull-in clearfix">

                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <label>Nome</label>
                  <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" maxlength="40" ng-model="university.name" required >
                </div>

              </div><!--./form-group-->

            </div>
            <footer class="panel-footer text-right bg-light lter">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
              <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="pop()">pop()</button>
            </footer>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>

</div>
```

My controller:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app.controller-university', ['ngCookies'])
  .controller('UniversityCtrl', ['$stateParams', '$scope', '$window', 'University',
    function($stateParams, $scope, $window, University ) {

      $scope.pop();       

  }]);
```

The file controllers.js. Where is the AppCtrl:

```
'use strict';

/* Controllers */

angular.module('app.controllers', ['pascalprecht.translate', 'ngCookies'])
  .controller('AppCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$translate', '$localStorage', '$window', 'toaster', 
    function(              $rootScope,   $scope,   $translate,   $localStorage,   $window,   toaster ) {
      // add 'ie' classes to html
      var isIE = !!navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE/i);
      isIE && angular.element($window.document.body).addClass('ie');
      isSmartDevice( $window ) && angular.element($window.document.body).addClass('smart');

      $scope.toaster = {
          type: 'success',
          title: 'Title',
          text: 'Message'
      };
      $scope.pop = function(){
          toaster.pop($scope.toaster.type, $scope.toaster.title, $scope.toaster.text);
      };

  }])
```

This is my app.js

```
'use strict';


// Declare app level module which depends on filters, and services
var app = angular.module('app', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngStorage',
    'ui.router',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ui.load',
    'ui.jq',
    'ui.validate',
    'oc.lazyLoad',
    'pascalprecht.translate',
    'app.filters',
    'app.services',
    'app.directives',
    'app.controllers',
    'app.controller-university',
    'UniversityService',
    'toaster',
  ])
.run(
  [          '$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams',
    function ($rootScope,   $state,   $stateParams) {
        $rootScope.$state = $state;
        $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;        
    }
  ]
)
.config(
  [          '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$controllerProvider', '$compileProvider', '$filterProvider', '$provide',
    function ($stateProvider,   $urlRouterProvider,   $controllerProvider,   $compileProvider,   $filterProvider,   $provide) {

        // lazy controller, directive and service
        app.controller = $controllerProvider.register;
        app.directive  = $compileProvider.directive;
        app.filter     = $filterProvider.register;
        app.factory    = $provide.factory;
        app.service    = $provide.service;
        app.constant   = $provide.constant;
        app.value      = $provide.value;

        $urlRouterProvider
            .otherwise('/app/dashboard-v1');
        $stateProvider
            .state('app', {
                abstract: true,
                url: '/app',
                templateUrl: 'tpl/app.html',              
            })

            .state('app.dashboard-v1', {
                url: '/dashboard-v1',
                templateUrl: 'tpl/app_dashboard_v1.html'
            })

            /////////////////////////
            // University
            //////////////////////////////////////////
            .state('app.university', {
                url: '/universidade',
                template: '<div ui-view class="fade-in-up"></div>'
            })
            .state('app.university.list', {
                url: '/listar',
                templateUrl: 'tpl/university/list.html',
                controller: 'UniversityCtrl',
            })
            .state('app.university.create', {
                url: '/criar',
                templateUrl: 'tpl/university/create.html',
                controller: 'UniversityCtrl',            
            })
```

Comment: WHere is `AppCtrl`  is it the parent of product ctrl? do you have necessary css as well?

Comment: Can you show more code? The rest of the app? The relevant HTML? The relevant CSS?

Comment: Why not move the code to open up the toaster in a seperate service, parameterize the invocation and then use it any controller you wish...

Comment: @JME I updated the post with more information about my app.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

you can use [angular-toaster](https://github.com/jirikavi/AngularJS-Toaster) reference it to your index.html page and also add the css, after that configure the directive at the bottom of the page as the following:

```
<toaster-container toaster-options="{
  'closeButton': false,
  'debug': false,
  'position-class': 'toast-top-right',
  'onclick': null,
  'showDuration': '200',
  'hideDuration': '1000',
  'timeOut': '5000',
  'extendedTimeOut': '1000',
  'showEasing': 'swing',
  'hideEasing': 'linear',
  'showMethod': 'fadeIn',
  'hideMethod': 'fadeOut'
}"></toaster-container>
```

then add it to your angular module dependencies as 'toaster' (you already did it well) so after that you'll be able to inject toaster service on any controller you want like the following:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('myController', [
    '$scope', 'toaster', function($scope,toaster) {

    toaster.pop('success', 'message', 'some message');

}]);
```

as the documentation says you can use a wide variety of options:

```
toaster.pop('success', "title", 'Its address is https://google.com.', 15000, 'trustedHtml', 'goToLink');
toaster.pop('success', "title", '<ul><li>Render html</li></ul>', 5000, 'trustedHtml');
toaster.pop('error', "title", '<ul><li>Render html</li></ul>', null, 'trustedHtml');
toaster.pop('wait', "title", null, null, 'template');
toaster.pop('warning', "title", "myTemplate.html", null, 'template');
toaster.pop('note', "title", "text");
```

so take a look to this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/4qpHwp?p=preview)

Comment: The toaster-container is in index.html?   :/

Comment: yes, no harm on that, you'll be able to use it across your whole application, that's the easier way to set it up and pretty straight fwd

Comment: Please note that the class name of 'positionClass': 'toast-top-right' in the configuration is not right. It should be 'position-class': 'toast-top-right'.

Comment: @YuMei I remember I took it from the documentation but it probably changed with newer version, I'll update it 'just in case'

Answer (score 7):

i use the toastr in the following manner:

Include toastr in your index html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/vendor/toastr/toastr.min.js"></script>
```

Define a factory which you can inject in any controller:

```
angular.module('app').value('ngToastr',toastr);

angular.module('app').factory('ngNotifier',function(ngToastr){
    return{
        notify: function(msg){
            ngToastr.success(msg);
        },
        notifyError: function(msg){
            ngToastr.error(msg);
        },
        notifyInfo: function(msg){
            ngToastr.info(msg);
        }
    }
});
```

After that you can inject this module in any controller:

```js
angular.module('app').controller('myCtrl',function($scope, ngNotifier) {
    ngNotifier.notifyError($scope.validationError);
});
```

Comment: That's great. It seems overkill at first, as you are just calling toaster methods inside another service, but it has a great value: if you ever need to drop toaster for another library in the future, you won't have to chase every single place were you would have called toaster directly. +1 on that.

Answer (score 1):

I like [@AndreiC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2667213/andreic)'s answer. A year later, here is a more robust factory service I use:

```
.factory('notifierService',function(toaster){
    return{
        notify: function(msg){
                toaster.pop('success', 'Update Successful', 'The ' + msg + ' setting was updated');
        },
        notifyError: function(msg){
                toaster.pop('error', 'Something Went Wrong', 'Please check with an administrator');
        },
        notifyInfo: function(msg){
                toaster.pop('info', 'Information', 'The ' + msg + 'just happened' );
        }
    };
})
```

> on the [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) promise

```
.$promise.then(function() {
     notifierService.notify('email server');
 });
```