# Put a line break (newline) into a toastr message in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, toastr

I'm using this [code](https://github.com/jirikavi/AngularJS-Toaster) to display toasts on an AngularJS site. I need to know how to put a line break (`<br/>`) into the body. When I use the options shown in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26309573/fire-notification-toaster-in-any-controller-angularjs/26414246#26414246), toastr renders the tag on screen, rather than interpreting it as HTML. How can I get a line break into a toast?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are two ways to allow some HTML tags, including line breaks, in a toast.

**Include `'body-output-type': 'trustedHtml'` in `toaster-options`:**

```
<toaster-container toaster-options="{
    'closeButton': false,
    'debug': false,
    'position-class': 'toast-bottom-right',
    'onclick': null,
    'showDuration': '200',
    'hideDuration': '1000',
    'timeOut': '5000',
    'extendedTimeOut': '1000',
    'showEasing': 'swing',
    'hideEasing': 'linear',
    'showMethod': 'fadeIn',
    'hideMethod': 'fadeOut', 
    'body-output-type': 'trustedHtml'
}"></toaster-container>
```

**Or include `'trustedHtml'` in a call to `toaster.pop()`:**

```
toaster.pop('success', 'Saved', 'Saved<br/>it!', 3000, 'trustedHtml');
```

or

```
toaster.pop({
    type: 'success',
    title: 'Saved',
    body: 'Saved<br/>it!',
    bodyOutputType: 'trustedHtml'
});
```

[Source](https://github.com/jirikavi/AngularJS-Toaster/blob/6b2f9101b2ffc0cab9e12126b24b3c69b9c84faf/README.md)

Comment: Just a minor observation, in the second example where you use the named parameters, the 'text' (it does not exist) property should be replaced by 'body'. Beyond that, thanks for the extensive answer.

Comment: @jmrivas I edited the answer, nice find