# how to display multi line message in the toastr ?

Tags: toastr

How to display multi line error message in the toastr ??

I have formatted my error message like below

```
"Please fix the following: \r\nFirst Name is required\r\nLast Name is required\r\nEmail Address is required\r\n"
```

But in the toasrt it shows in the single line. Please help

Comment: i believe toastr is adding the string as html tags.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to put a line break into a toastr message in AngularJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254459/how-to-put-a-line-break-into-a-toastr-message-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As told by Dr.Stitch , toastr using the string as html so we have to add  for the new line :

```
Please fix the following: </br>First Name is required</br>Last Name is required</br>Email Address is required</br>
```

***- An update: 15/12/2020:***

**For the version 12+ :**

```
toastr.success('Please fix the following: </br>First Name is required</br>Last Name is required</br>Email Address is required</br>', '', { closeButton: true, timeOut: 4000, progressBar: true, allowHtml: true });
```

This will work !!! thank you for the help.

Answer (score 18):

allowHtml: true

```
toastr.success('\'Second Review\' validation has started. </br>All SME\'s and Reviewers will get an email notification', '', { closeButton: true, timeOut: 4000, progressBar: true, allowHtml: true });
```

Answer (score 16):

Please note in

> ng-toaster v12.1.0

it's `enableHtml` instead of `allowHtml` with `<br />` as HTML.

Might also be changed in older versions.

Answer (score 1):

import toastr service first and than write your message and enable HTML

```
this.toastr.success('First Name is required<br />Last Name is required<br />Email Address is required<br />', { 
enableHtml: true
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
use '\n' in your string and add this style
```

> white-space : pre-line !important;

Comment: I think this answer is the best one because it avoids enabling HTML which can be a security issue