# Styling ionic 2 toast

Tags: toast, ionic2

Is there any way to style the text message within an ionic 2 toast?

I have tried this:

```js
    let toast = Toast.create({
      message: "Some text on one line. <br /><br /> Some text on another line.",
      duration: 15000,
      showCloseButton: true,
      closeButtonText: 'Got it!',
      dismissOnPageChange: true
    });

    toast.onDismiss(() => {
      console.log('Dismissed toast');
    });

    this.nav.present(toast);
  }
```

But clearly you can't use html in the text so I am guessing the answer to my question is no?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You must add  'cssClass: "yourCssClassName"' in your toastCtrl function.

```
 let toast = Toast.create({
      message: "Some text on one line. <br /><br /> Some text on another line.",
      duration: 15000,
      showCloseButton: true,
      closeButtonText: 'Got it!',
      dismissOnPageChange: true,
      cssClass: "yourCssClassName",
    });
```

than you can add any feature to the your css class. But your css feature went outside the default page'css. Exmp:

```
   page-your.page.scss.name {
     //bla bla
    }
 .yourCssClassName {
   text-align:center;
  }
```

Comment: I was putting the class inside of page-your.page.scss.name your answer helped me out!! Thanks @Burhan Gül!!! :D

Comment: This only aligns the text. The html tags `<br />` won't work.

Comment: I have to use `!important` to `text-align:center` to take effect: `text-align: center !important;` otherwise it will not work!

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS i was also doing the same mistake. Can someone tell me the reason of putting it outside the page-your.page.scss.name.

Answer (score 25):

I was able to achieve a toaster color change by adding a custom class on the toaster create

```
let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
    message: 'Foobar was successfully added.',
    duration: 5000,
    cssClass: "toast-success"
  });
  toast.present();
}
```

In that pages scss file i then went outside the default nested page name  ( because the toaster is **NOT** inside the root of ion page name thing). And all though this is a bit hacky i just explicitly targeted the next `div` element after the custom class that i added

```
.toast-success {
  > div{
       background-color:#32db64!important;
   }
}
```

I say its hacky because you have to use the `!important` on it. You can avoid the !important by  wrapping the `.toast-success` with `.md,.ios,.wp{...`

You can override the style default by overriding the main toaster variables in the `theme/variables.scss` file.

```
$toast-ios-background:(#32db64);
$toast-md-background:(#32db64);
$toast-wp-background:(#32db64);
```

This will only override the default value though and not a custom value. there are a few more variables that can be styled as well.

Comment: This is working. I had to remove the `background-color` I had defined in class `.toast-message` for the custom cssClass background to be visible.

Comment: You should emphasize that you put .toast-success outside of the page-name thing. I overlooked it and spent 1 hour debugging because I was careless. =(

Comment: Ok the div stuff did the trick it was changing all of my screen to color red because I was missing the div :(

Answer (score 7):

First, import toast controller from `ionic-angular` and make object of that in constructor.

```
import { ToastController } from "ionic-angular";

constructor(private _tc: ToastController) {
}
```

After that wherever you want to show your toast message write that.

```
let options = {
  message: "Your toast message show here",
  duration: 3000,
  cssClass: "toast.scss"
 };

this._tc.create(options).present();
```

Here is my scss:

```
.toast-message {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Or you can check best example from this [link](https://github.com/jirikavi/AngularJS-Toaster/blob/6b2f9101b2ffc0cab9e12126b24b3c69b9c84faf/README.md). I think it will help you. :)

Or else check the answer on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254459/how-to-put-a-line-break-into-a-toastr-message-in-angularjs).

Answer (score 6):

If you define your own css class in app.scss (not in page.scss) 
you can style it with .toast-wrapper and .toast.message
No need to use `> div{`

Example:

```
.yourtoastclass {
  .toast-wrapper {
    background: blue;
    opacity: 0.8;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .toast-message {
    font-size: 3.0rem;
    color: white;
  }
}
```

in theme/variables.scss you can make a default

Example (red and little transparent):

```
$toast-width:   75%;  /* default 100% */
$toast-ios-background: rgba(153, 0, 0, .8);
$toast-md-background: rgba(153, 0, 0, 0.8);
```

Comment: Thank You @Ralf. How can we set `border-radius: 5px;` and `text-align: center;` in theme/variable.scss? And how we can align toast to display to center of screen (when width is not 100%)?

Comment: $toast-ios-border-radius .65rem

Answer (score 4):

Ionic 2 provide a very useful way to override their component style you can override the toaster SASS variable in src/theme/variables.scss  by adding

```
$toast-ios-title-color: #f00 ;
$toast-md-title-color:#f00;
```

this will override the default style please refer to this [Overriding Ionic Sass variable](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/overriding-ionic-variables/)

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish, however you need to modify the toast component template itself.

Via explorer:
\node_modules\ionic-angular\components\toast\toast.js

Change line 194 (template):
`{{d.message}}` to `<div [innerHTML]='d.message'></div>`

Comment: Not advised as you will be overwriting the core ionic files and therefor any updates from ionic will break the changes you made. It will also make maintaining the project a pain. Especially if other devs are working on it.

Comment: this is however the right answer to this question. So far ionic toast do not support that behaviour. Maybe it will be good to request an update

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to change any of the message styling in the css using `.toast-message` selector:

```
.toast-message { 
    font-family: Helvetica,
    color: red
}
```

Or, if you look at the docs (http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/toast/Toast/) there is a cssClass property you can use to assign your toast a specific class and then style that.

Comment: Yes I can see how to change the font etc. But I need to change the layout of the message with paragraphs and indents etc.

Comment: Ahh, I don't think there is a clean way to do that as of right now because the message takes a string over html (as you pointed out above). You could potentially edit the DOM directly after the component was created but this would be messy. Maybe let Ionic know that this feature would be useful

Comment: Thanks Pat that is what I feared.

Answer (score 1):

Change toast background color and opacity:

```
let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
      message: msg,
      duration: 3000,
      position: 'bottom',
      cssClass: 'changeToast'
    });
```

and add `app.scss`:

```
.changeToast{.toast-wrapper {opacity: 0.6; border-radius: 5px !important; text-align: center; background: color($colors, primary);}};
```

It's used with `.toast-message`

Answer (score 1):

I tried all above, still didn't work, therefore I come across a new solution, you need cssClass outside of page css declaration:

```
let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
          message: msg,
          duration: 3000,
          position: 'bottom',
          cssClass: 'toastcolor'
        });
```

post-list.scss like this

```
page-post-list {

}
.toastcolor .toast-message {
    background-color:skyblue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about old Ionic versions, but in Ionic 5 you can't directly change inner CSS since it's encapsulated in the shadow

```
<ion-select>
  #shadow-root
    <div class="toast-container" part="container">
       ...
    </div>
</ion-select>
```

so, to change .toast-container (for example) in your `cssClass` you should use:

```
.my-custom-class::part(container) {
    flex-direction: column;
}

.my-custom-class {
    .toast-container {
        flex-direction: column; // will not work
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using ionic v5 with angular and
according to: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/toast#css-shadow-parts

you can do something like this:

```
::ng-deep{
    ion-toast::part(container) {
        ...
    }
    ion-toast::part(message) {
        ...
    }
}
```