# Is it possible to have newline character in Ionic2 toast?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I tried both **\n**  and  **< br/ >**, but unfortunately not working!

**Is this Possible ?**

```js
//Displaying toast to welcome user!
let user = this.currentUser();
//console.log(user);
let toast = Toast.create({
  message: 'Hi ' + user.email + '! <br/> Welcome to My App',
  duration: 5000,
  position: 'bottom'
});

toast.onDismiss(() => {
  console.log('Dismissed toast');
});

this.nav.present(toast);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37118385/styling-ionic-2-toast

Comment: that doesn't resolved problem!

Comment: Right. It's a similar question, where the answer appears to be "no, you can't".  There's also a link to the docs.

Comment: You're wrong, Matty. It IS possible, see my answer. Furthermore it's not a similar question. Ankit asked whether it's possible to have a line break, the other guy asked whether it's possible to render HTML in Toasts.

Answer (score 19):

Actually it IS possible. You can do the following:

```
.toast-message {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

and `\n` for a line-break.

Note: Take a look at `home.ts` and `style.css`.

See [working plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ltfspRq0mPir2KdZ3rAg?p=preview)

Comment: Somehow it is not working in actual application, I written same code over plunkr (working!) but not working in my type-script file. OR this may be the issue in Ionic2

Comment: Ok this is working. I first used `<br/>` but it works using '\n` as in the answer.

Comment: I didn't have to do the css, \n worked out of the box. <br/> was a deadend

Answer (score 11):

Although @iWork solution works for many situation but if you have `close` button in your toast it will be pushed out of screen.

So you can use these style sheet instead:

```
.toast-message {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

p.s you need to use `\n` for line break in your string